# bind paste event not being called in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In my code I have binded a paste event to html (I have even tried binding it to the body) like so:

```
$("body").bind("paste", function (e) {
     console.log("Hereeee");
});
```

or

```
$("html").bind("paste", function (e) {
     console.log("Hot in Herrrree");
});
```

Neither of them work in IE 11 meaning the console.logs are not appearing, but does work in Chrome and Safari.....what do I have to do to get it to work in IE 11?

Comment: have you tried `.bind('input', function(e) )` ?

Comment: is that the same as the paste event? And will this work in Chrome, Safari and IE?

Comment: I am on my apple computer now so i can't test it on IE. But `input` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) fires any any input event: keypress, paste, change, .. (but It does not work on most mobile devices)

Answer (score 0):

What if you use .on instead?

```
$('html').on('paste', function (e) {
     console.log("Hot in Herrrree");
});
```

Comment: Just tried that...did not work, I even tried right clicking any on in the body and went to select paste, but its disabled....does that mean my clipboard is empty?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to paste something in some elements in IE then the paste event can be fired. You could check the code below: if I paste something in the textbox, the paste event will be fired.

```js
$("html").bind("paste", function (e) {
    console.log("Hereeee");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```